# Error DBLink from 10g to 12c

Tags: oracle10g, oracle12c

I have created a database link from my 10g database to 12c database. When I am trying to access table using 10g database it works fine. But when we try to execute the procedure from 10g database, it popups following error

```
SQL> exec  popcust@abcd;
BEGIN popcust@abcd; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'POPCUST@ABCD' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

When we describe a procedure from 10g DB. it comes with like this.

```
SQL> desc popcust@abcd;
PROCEDURE st@abcd
```

Please can somebody help me

Comment: Why does desc report the remote name as `st`? I'm not sure if your obfuscation of real names has hidden the problem.

Comment: Did you check whether procedure POPCUST exists in schema that database link points to?

Comment: yes, it exists in that schema. Not sure why it truncates the name